# how to show / hide WPF window by blur effect

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF window. I want to add blurring effect. I.e. When i say `Show()` or `Close()` it should blur into view and blur out of view.

I tried using `Effect = new BlurEffect()`, but i believe it is when windows is visible

Edit:
I figured out that I could actually control the **opacity**, so I have decided to fade the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me.

```
        var _sb = new Storyboard();
        var da = new DoubleAnimation(0.0, 1.0, new Duration(time)) {AutoReverse = false};
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));
        _sb.Children.Clear();
        _sb.Children.Add(da);
        this.Opacity = 0;
        Show();
        _sb.Begin(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cannot blur an entire window (Window being defined as the Chrome window element) you can blur any UI element within the window.

You can accomplish this by creating an animation within Blend. Add the blur effect and then create a storyboard. You can title it whatever (BlurIn). Then within the time line set the start and ending of your blur effect. Place this animation either in a resource dictionary or within the xaml page you are triggering the effect on.

You can then call this animation via code like

```
private void BeginAnimation()
        {
            stroyboard1.Begin();
        }
```

I don't know how you have your app set up but depending upon how you are using UI Elements, views you can have objects or views appear with this blur effect applied onLoad or on an event handler.

Comment: Can't you apply the blurring to a container within the window, though?I'm not sure how well that works out with a transparent window background and the resulting blur into transparency, though.

Comment: not sure what you mean by container? If you mean a UI Element such as a grid, stack panel, canvas, then yes. You can apply an effect to these objects. However it is not possible to apply this to a true window container.